# smart table angularjs module fixed table header is not working on safari

Tags: css, angularjs, smart-table

I am using smart table angular js based module. I implemented this module in my project and realized its not rendering properly on safari. Then I went through the example given on smart table site and realized that sample example given there is also having problem on safar. Following is plunker having fixed table header code sample.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/fcdXKE?p=preview
```

HTML Markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.25" data-semver="1.2.25" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src=smart-table.debug.js></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table st-table="displayed" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="firstName">first name</th>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="lastName">last name</th>
        <th st-ratio="10" st-sort="age">age</th>
        <th st-ratio="30" st-sort="email">email</th>
        <th st-ratio="20" st-sort="balance">balance</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in displayed">
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.firstName}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.lastName | uppercase}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="10">{{row.age}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="30">{{row.email}}</td>
        <td st-ratio="20">{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
            <div  st-items-by-page="20" st-pagination=""></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table'])
    .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

        var
            nameList = ['Pierre', 'Pol', 'Jacques', 'Robert', 'Elisa'],
            familyName = ['Dupont', 'Germain', 'Delcourt', 'bjip', 'Menez'];

        function createRandomItem() {
            var
                firstName = nameList[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                lastName = familyName[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)],
                age = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
                email = firstName + lastName + '@whatever.com',
                balance = Math.random() * 3000;

            return{
                firstName: firstName,
                lastName: lastName,
                age: age,
                email: email,
                balance: balance
            };
        }


        $scope.displayed = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
            $scope.displayed.push(createRandomItem());
        }
    }])
    .directive('stRatio',function(){
        return {
          link:function(scope, element, attr){
            var ratio=+(attr.stRatio);

            element.css('width',ratio+'%');

          }
        };
    });
```

style.css

```
table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 500px; /* this can vary */
}

table * {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
}

thead {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    display: inline-block;
}

thead > tr, tbody > tr, tfoot > tr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

thead, tfoot {
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

th, tbody td {
    width: 20%; /* this can vary */
    overflow-x: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: inline-block;
}

tfoot {
    display: inline-block;
}

tfoot td {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You will see that on safari, the table header is not fixed on page scroll; however same works fine on other browser.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same problem this morning. Like you I was using the example code from smart table webpage.

The problem is that the flex properties in the css are not compatible with Safari. For a better cross-browser compatibility:

Put this instead of display:flex (it must be in this order):

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
```

Put this instead of flex-direction:row (the same with column) :

```
-moz-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
```

Put this instead of flex-wrap:nowrap :

```
-moz-flex-wrap: nowrap;
-webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
```

And finally this instead of flex-shrink:0 :

```
-moz-flex-shrink: 0;
-webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
flex-shrink: 0;
```

I could test it in Safari 8 but it should work in Safari 6+ (I'd be grateful if somebody could confirm this).

For more information about flexbox I recommend you [A complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). For cross-browser compatibility go [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/#fallbacks).

Comment: Updated working plunker for Safari http://plnkr.co/edit/hCG8ZHLpqxqIfGh7yG8q?p=preview